# API GET Request getting different result from whats on database record

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

My setup is Vue + Laravel and the request is done via axios.

I'm getting different value from whats on the database.

**The query**

```
User::where('role', 'partner')->select('id', 'partner')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);
```

**Database Record**

[image]

**Response to axios GET request on network tab**,
you see here the `partner` value is different from what's in the database, its like the last 2 digit are transform into closer 10th values always ends with `0`

[image]

If I tried opening the end-point directly on the browser, I'm getting the correct value

[image]

I even tried copying all the headers from axios request to emulate the request on vscode rest-client and I'm also getting the correct values

[image]

The axios configuration is this

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
  const token = store.getters['auth/token']
  if (token) {
    request.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
  }

  const locale = store.getters['lang/locale']
  if (locale) {
    request.headers.common['Accept-Language'] = locale
  }

  // request.headers['X-Socket-Id'] = Echo.socketId()

  return request
})
```

I'm lost on where to even begin debugging this just scratching my head.

Comment: I am assuming you are having issues with PHP max int. You cannot have 10000000000000000000000000000000 because you want as an INT, there is a limit to it... echo this `echo PHP_INT_MAX` and check if that value is bigger or smaller than your database numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has two number types: Number and BigInt.

The most frequently-used number type, Number, is a 64-bit floating point IEEE 754 number.
The largest exact integral value of this type is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` which is: +/- 9,007,199,254,740,991.

The `partner` values are bigger `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` so some operations may not work properly. `x == x + 1` returns `true`

To solve it, simply use `string` instead.

Comment: ah, that makes sense, wasn't aware about that. I can just cast this as string on Laravel, Thank you so much